# events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do on authetication and authorization, from some of the post i found out to install npm, I've install npm too still am unable to solve the error:

```
$ node blog.js
Blog API is starting on port 6379
 events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^

 Error: listen EADDRINUSE
             at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
             at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
             at listen (net.js:1064:10)
             at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
             at Function.app.listen  (./node_modules/express/lib/application.js:531:24)
             at Object.<anonymous> (./api/blog.js:9:5)
             at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
             at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
             at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
             at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Comment: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE` means some other program is already listening on the port your server wants to open.

Answer (score 6):

There is an error code in your dump:

EADDRRINUSE which is short for "error address in use" which usually occurs when the port your node.js server ist trying to start is already in use.

Check what port is supposed to be used and figure out what else is already running at that port. It might even be your blog.js you started earlier.

---

**Edit:**

Port 6379 is the default port for the redis, which you probably have already ... you should use a different port. If your trying it locally just to start developing and figure out how things works, keep the 3001 and start up a browser at `http://localhost:3001/`

The Allow-Origin Header should contain the correct hostname under which your server is reachable, as long as your running it locally `http://localhost` should be fine, a port might be necessary.

Comment: thankyou for your reply.................                 the port is 6379, am novice to this and am trying to change the port of blog.js as it mentioned me to do                                                                           -->:(Edit api/blog.js and replace the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin to match your server configuration.)                                     and here is the code line                                              ->[ res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');]       but i get trouble what to insert in the above given code line:

Comment: Port 6379 should not be used for BlogJS, already used by the redis server. Updated Answer