# events.js:173 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am not able to execute "npm start" command. I am getting this error while running this command.
node -v : v12.0.0
npm -v : 6.9.0

I have tried to reinstall all the software.
even I have also changed the port number and try to execute the code.

what should I do?

```
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.exit (internal/child_process.js:248:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:431:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:17)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.exit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:431:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dhruvi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-30T01_57_22_780Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try `yarn install` and `yarn start`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525253/events-js72-throw-er-unhandled-error-event)

Comment: You should give us more information :-)  If there is an error dump you should provide that.  This error message merely says that you have an error which is not handled.  The information which contains the clue about the actual error... that will be in the dump.

Comment: @smurp I have edited my question by adding the code. Can you please check it once. thanks in advance

Comment: @Junius L. 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ----
getting this error,

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the node_modules folder, and reinstall npm modules.

```
npm install
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure all the global & local packages that are being used in the scripts are installed, in your case it could be `webpack-cli & yarn` wasn't installed globally & you are trying to access it using your script.
2. All Export & PATH environments are setup correctly
3. rm -rf node_modules && npm install